# R Regex: Parenthesis Not Acting as Metacharacter

Tags: regex, r, metacharacters

I am trying to split a string by the group "%in%" and the character "@".  All documentation and everything I can find says that parenthesis are metacharacters used for grouping in R regex.  So the code

```
    > strsplit('example%in%aa(bbb)aa@cdef', '[(%in%)@]', perl=TRUE)
```

SHOULD give me

```
    [[1]]
    [1] "example" "aa(bbb)aa"      "cdef"
```

That is, it should leave the parentheses in "aa(bbb)aa" alone, because the parentheses in the matching expression are not escaped.  But instead it ACTUALLY gives me

```
    [[1]]
    [1] "example" ""   ""    ""    "aa"    "bbb"   "aa"    "cdef"
```

as if the parentheses were not metacharacters!  What is up with this and how can I fix it? Thanks!

This is true with and without the argument perl=TRUE in strsplit.

Comment: Character classes translation is `Each character stands alone`. What you have is equivalent to `(?: \( | % | i | n | @ | \) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what documentation you're reading, but the *Extended Regular Expressions* section in `?regex` says:

> Most metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class. ...
>   (Only '^ - \ ]' are special inside character classes.)

You don't need to create a character class.  Just use "or" `|` (you likely don't need to group `"%in%"` either, but it shouldn't hurt anything):

```
> strsplit('example%in%aa(bbb)aa@cdef', '(%in%)|@', perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "example"   "aa(bbb)aa" "cdef"
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `[` or `(` here , just this :

```
strsplit('example%in%aa(bbb)aa@cdef', '%in%|@')
[[1]]
[1] "example"   "aa(bbb)aa" "cdef"
```

Comment: What is the difference between `[` and `|` then?

Comment: Not sure that this will help , but `[` is a character class and `|` is the or operator ...

Answer (score 2):

Inside character class `[]`, most of the characters lose their special meaning, including `()`.

You might want this regex instead:

```
'%in%|@'
```